# ajax control toolkit datepicker show calender date between 18 years to 90 years from current date

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, datepicker, ajaxcontroltoolkit

How can I set the date calender of ajax toolkit datepicker to display date range between 18 years to 90 years only from current date using javascript ?

i.e., today is 2016-02-19 so the calender date will start from 1998-02-19 to 1926-02-19. How can I do this using javascript?

I tried doing this using C#, but it is not working.

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Date Of Birth</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB" runat="server" CssClass="txt-control" />
    <asp:Image ID="calendarImg1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/calendar_month.gif"
        Style="cursor: pointer" />
    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="dp_DOB" runat="server" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" PopupButtonID="calendarImg1"
        TargetControlID="txtDOB" CssClass="calender" />
</div>
```

My code behind. When adding StartDate and EndDate I cannot browse the calender it shows only this month's calender. But when I remove the StartDate EndDate I can browse the calender.

```
dp_DOB.StartDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-18);
dp_DOB.EndDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-90).AddDays(1);
```

PS: Guys please post reason why you voted to close my question, better you post the answer of the question, if it is simple for you.

Comment: Do server StartDate and EndDate properties not suit your needs?